# Mapping {a, b, c} to {1, 0}

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

There are eight different functions $f: \{a, b, c\} \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$ List them all. Diagrams will suffice.

From my understanding, they should be: $f(a) \rightarrow 0 $, $f(a) \rightarrow 1, $ $f(b) \rightarrow 0 $, $f(b) \rightarrow 1, $ $f(c) \rightarrow 0 $, $f(c) \rightarrow 1, $

However that's only six. Any idea on the two that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One  mapping is not about mapping one element, but it is about mapping the whole set into $\{0,1\}$

For example the following specifies ONE map:
$$f(a)=f(b)=1,f(c)=0$$

So could you list all the rest?

Answer (score 0):

Each one of the relations you defined is not an individual function. An individual function looks like:

$$
f(a) = 1, \
f(b) = 1, \
f(c) = 0
$$

There are eight of them. Just imagine you have three bins labeled $a, b$ and $c$ and you can put a 1 or a 0 with replacement in each bin.

Answer (score 0):

Each function must assign one and only one element of the range to each each element of the domain. So one possible function is f(a)=1, f(b)=1, f(c)=0. These all describe one function, they are not 3 different functions.